# Apple Wallet Extension

Tags: swift, apple-wallet

I am working on banking application and there is a requirement where I have to implement wallet extension which has been introduced in 2014. I want to add bank cards though wallet app. Below is the flow I am trying to achieve

1. Already have apple entitlement
2. Open wallet app and press + button which is at top right. After this ideally Banking app name should display
3. After selection of baking app authentication must happen and if that is successful card should get added to wallet

I am new to app extension and really not sure how to use UI and NON UI extension. Could you please help me with this. After displaying banking app on click of + button how call will go to NON UI extension

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am stuck in the same boat now.

Comment: Same i'm also stuck in the same boat.